# does firefox support dressing 2nd level lists eg. li ul li > a

Tags: css

Can not get firefox to use css on 2 level menu ie and chrome do use the css but firefox ignores it any ideas? its the hover part it seems it doesnt support is there an other way of writing it?

```
/* Level 2 */
.accordion li ol li { 
background: #eeeeee;
font-size: 12px; 
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.accordion li ol li:hover { 
background: #ffffff;
}
.accordion li ol li > a { 
background: #ffffff;
color: #777777;
font-size: 12px; 
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
transition: color ease-in 99999999s
}
.accordion li ol li:hover > a { 
color: #5CACFC;
}
```

Comment: Set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us to play with

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mzmjR/2/   fiddle away thank you

Comment: AHHHH its late just saw it had color transition on 99999999s strange that chrome or explorer didnt use it though?

Comment: If you want chrome to take for ever to change, you must set -webkit-transition: forever   :-)